# Linking to js file does not work

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function refresh() {
  var currentDay = new Date();
  var breakStart = new Date(2017, 3, 21, 15, 20);
  var breakEnd = new Date(2017, 4, 1, 8, 40);
  var diff = (breakStart.getTime() - currentDay.getTime()) / 1000;
  var diff2 = (breakEnd.getTime() - currentDay.getTime()) / 1000;

  dayz = Math.floor(diff2 / 86400)
  diff2 %= 86400;
  hourz = Math.floor(diff2 / 3600)
  diff2 %= 3600;
  minutez = Math.floor(diff2 / 60)
  diff2 %= 60;
  secondz = Math.floor(diff2 / 1)
  diff2 %= 1;

  days = Math.floor(diff / 86400)
  diff %= 86400;
  hours = Math.floor(diff / 3600)
  diff %= 3600;
  minutes = Math.floor(diff / 60)
  diff %= 60;
  seconds = Math.floor(diff / 1)
  diff %= 1;


  if (days == 1) {
    document.getElementById("final").innerHTML = ("There is " + days + " day, " + hours + " hours, " + minutes + " minutes, and " + seconds + " seconds left until spring break.");
  }


  if (days > 1) {
    document.getElementById("final").innerHTML = ("There are " + days + " days, " + hours + " hours, " + minutes + " minutes, and " + seconds + " seconds left until spring break.");
  }

  if (days == 0) {
    document.getElementById("final").innerHTML = ("There are " + days + " days, " + hours + " hours, " + minutes + " minutes, and " + seconds + " seconds left until spring break.");
  }

  if (dayz > 1 && dayz < 9) {
    document.getElementById("final").innerHTML = ("We are in break! Hooray! There are " + dayz + " days, " + hourz + " hours, " + minutez + " minutes, and " + secondz + " seconds left in spring break");
  }

}

setInterval(refresh, 1000);
```

```css
   <style> @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300');
   p {
     font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
     font-size: 400%;
     color: ;
   }
   
   </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPEhtml>

<embed src="Chamelion.mp3" autostart="true" loop="true" width="2" height="0">

<center>
  <p>SPRING BREAK:</p>
</center>
<center>
  <p id="final"></p>
</center>
```

Hello, 
This program I wrote calculates the amount of time it is until spring break. I put the below line of code my html but this does not seem to work to link to my js file. On the code snippet here it works, but i'm trying to use an external script. 
Sorry for the big block of code. Anything helps!

Seb

EDIT:
The code as it is in my editor:

```
   <embed src="Chamelion.mp3" autostart="true" loop="true"
   width="2" height="0">
   </embed>

   <script src="spring.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <style>
   @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300');
   p{
   font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
   font-size: 400%;
   color: ;
   }
   </style>
   <center><p>SPRING BREAK:</p></center>
   <center><p id="final"></p></center>
   <center><img src="bunny.jpg" width="300"></center>
```

Comment: Assure the _spring.js_ file is in the correct directory

Comment: Is spring.js in the same folder as your html?

Comment: Yes spring.js is in the same folder as my html

Comment: @SebastienBolh can you show us exactly how the code is structured within your editor. just copy and paste it here as it is ;).

Comment: @SebastienBolh I mean copy your entire HTML markup as it is and paste it here. the markup you've shown doesn't include the script tag, you've shown it separately. to put it simply just copy your entire code **how it is** and paste it here.

Comment: <!DOCTYPEhtml>
<head>

  <embed src="Chamelion.mp3" autostart="true" loop="true"
  width="2" height="0">
  </embed>

  <script src="spring.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300');
  p{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 400%;
    color: ;
  }
  </style>
  <center><p>SPRING BREAK:</p></center>
  <center><p id="final"></p></center>
  <center><img src="bunny.jpg" width="300"></center>

Comment: I also put it in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problems seems to be that you've loaded the script before the targeted `final` exists in document object model.

place the code below as the last line of the `<body>` element:

```
<body>
  ...
  ...
  ...
  <script src="spring.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place the line at the end just before the  tag

```
...
    <script src="spring.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw I don't think Mr.w is jumping to conclusions. The script is loaded before the targeted `final` exists in DOM.